# RegExp to match a segment of a URL

Tags: php, regex, preg-match

I'm trying to use RegExp to match a segment of a URL.

The URL in question is this:

```
http://www.example.com/news/region/north-america/
```

As I need this regex for the WordPress URL Rewrite API, the *subject* will only be the path section of the URL:

```
news/region/north-america
```

In the above example I need to be able to extract the north-america portion of the path, however when pagination is used the path becomes something like this:

```
news/region/north-america/page/2
```

Where I still only need to extract the north-america portion.

The RegExp I've come up with is as follows:

```
^news/region/(.*?)/(.*?)?/?(.*?)?$
```

However this does not match for `news/region/north-america` only `news/region/north-america/page/2`

From what I can tell I need to make the trailing slash after `north-america` optional, but adding `/?` doesn't seem to work.

Comment: Thank you - this works - if you add as a solution I'll be happy to flagged it as accepted. Many thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[georg's](https://stackoverflow.com/users/989121/georg) suggested rule work like a charm:

```
^news/region/(.*?)(?:/(.*?)/(.*?))?$
```

For those interested in the application of this regex, I used it in the WP Rewrite API to grab the custom taxonomy and page number (if present) and assign the relevant matches to the the WP re-write:

> $newRules['news/region/(.*?)(?:/(.*?)/(.*?))?$']='index.php?region=$matches[1]&forcetemplate=news&paged=$matches[3]';

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
preg_match('/news\/region\/(.*?)\//',"http://www.example.com/news/region/north-america/page/2",$matches);
```

the $matches[1] will give you the output. as "north-america".

Answer (score 0):

You should match using this regex:

```
^news/region/([^/]+)
```

This will give you `news/region/north-america` even when URI becomes `/news/region/north-america/page/2`

Comment: Thanks for the feedback, but this includes the news/region portion too - I only need the north-america part.